# Optimization through Iteration

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, z3, z3py

Hi I am trying to find the minimum value of an objective function which have some constraints, through very basic iterative process. The problem is that due to floating point issue program never terminates. I need accuracy up till 15 decimal digits and I dont want z3 or python to explore any value above that accuracy. Following is the code: the accurate result which I have calculated through Mathematica is: a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4, e=5, f=6 and corresponding minimum value of objective function is: 2.06846*10^-14. Is it possible that I can calculate the same result?

Following is the code: (Please copy paste to run it as expression is very long)

```
from sympy import*
from z3 import*


#working simple optimization example
# Given formula and set of constraints (cons), find the model that minimize the value of X 
# using at-most Max iterations.

def abs(X):
    return If(X >= 0,x,-x)



def Opti(cons, X, Max):

    #set_option(precision=15) 
    s = Solver()
    s.add(cons)
    last_model  = None
    i = 0
    while True:

        r = s.check()
        if r == unsat:
            if last_model != None:
                return last_model
            else:
                return unsat
        if r == unknown:
            raise Z3Exception("failed")

        last_model = s.model()
       # if last_model[X]<0:
       #     last_model[X]=-last_model[X]
        s.add(X < last_model[X])

        i = i + 1
        if (i > Max):
            raise Z3Exception("Solution not found, maximum number of iterations was reached")




a = Int('a')
b = Int('b')    
c = Int('c')
d = Int('d')
e = Int('e')    
f = Int('f')
x = Real('x')
y= Real('y')

X = Real('X')
Y = Real('Y')


cons=[ a>0,b>0,c>0,d>0,e>0,f>0, x== (abs((3608946673948233*d)/4503599627370496 + (274464355232027*e)/2251799813685248 - (274464355232027*e**2)/(4*(562949953421312*e + 562949953421312*f - 5536725273124715)) - 1519633732185043491981133247305/1267650600228229401496703205376) + abs((4636666003778669*b)/9007199254740992 + (1118552746194141*c)/2251799813685248 + (29870012493936382538794142709149*b)/(9007199254740992*(9007199254740992*b + 9007199254740992*c - 6442131581095921)) + (7205863971378845991234609198861*c)/(2251799813685248*(9007199254740992*b + 9007199254740992*c - 6442131581095921)) - (4636666003778669*b*(b + c))/(9007199254740992*b + 9007199254740992*c - 6442131581095921) - (4474210984776564*c*(b + c))/(9007199254740992*b + 9007199254740992*c - 6442131581095921)) + abs((274464355232027*e)/2251799813685248 + (1519633732185043491981133247305*e)/(2251799813685248*(562949953421312*e + 562949953421312*f - 5536725273124715)) - (274464355232027*e*(e + f))/(4*(562949953421312*e + 562949953421312*f - 5536725273124715))) + abs((792979490709637*b)/1125899906842624 - (901702497811663*c)/2251799813685248 + (4891864612675574504296157138923*b)/(1125899906842624*(2251799813685248*b + 2251799813685248*c - 6168967381864879)) - (5562573297146236482969456283777*c)/(2251799813685248*(2251799813685248*b + 2251799813685248*c - 6168967381864879)) - (1585958981419274*b*(b + c))/(2251799813685248*b + 2251799813685248*c - 6168967381864879) + (901702497811663*c*(b + c))/(2251799813685248*b + 2251799813685248*c - 6168967381864879)) + abs((8431533077325893*b)/18014398509481984 - (708586604185451*c)/4503599627370496 + (54368167798740930523060826625213*b)/(18014398509481984*(1125899906842624*b + 1125899906842624*c - 6448194806345241)) - (4569104460954436146783095288691*c)/(4503599627370496*(1125899906842624*b + 1125899906842624*c - 6448194806345241)) - (8431533077325893*b*(b + c))/(16*(1125899906842624*b + 1125899906842624*c - 6448194806345241)) + (708586604185451*c*(b + c))/(4*(1125899906842624*b + 1125899906842624*c - 6448194806345241))) + abs((4474210984776564*c**2)/(9007199254740992*b + 9007199254740992*c - 6442131581095921) - (177126692422487*d)/1125899906842624 - (1118552746194141*c)/2251799813685248 + (4636666003778669*b*c)/(9007199254740992*b + 9007199254740992*c - 6442131581095921) + 7205863971378845991234609198861/20282409603651670423947251286016) + abs((2035957719017013*b**2)/(1024*(140737488355328*b + 140737488355328*c - 2249387656040967)) - (2035957719017013*b)/144115188075855872 - (2035957719017013*a)/144115188075855872 + (2939179565022695*b*c)/(64*(140737488355328*b + 140737488355328*c - 2249387656040967)) + 4579658161378192576066497971571/20282409603651670423947251286016) + abs((5056216978909333*b)/36028797018963968 + (3060017963484179*c)/4503599627370496 + (27994884333529598097197586465095*b)/(36028797018963968*(562949953421312*b + 562949953421312*c - 5536725273124715)) + (16942478794638475145271796383985*c)/(4503599627370496*(562949953421312*b + 562949953421312*c - 5536725273124715)) - (5056216978909333*b*(b + c))/(64*(562949953421312*b + 562949953421312*c - 5536725273124715)) - (3060017963484179*c*(b + c))/(8*(562949953421312*b + 562949953421312*c - 5536725273124715))) + abs((2939179565022695*c**2)/(64*(140737488355328*b + 140737488355328*c - 2249387656040967)) - (2230056655377591*d)/2251799813685248 - (2939179565022695*c)/9007199254740992 + (2035957719017013*b*c)/(1024*(140737488355328*b + 140737488355328*c - 2249387656040967)) + 6611354232449908862093204746065/1267650600228229401496703205376) + abs((3860418273669689*e)/9007199254740992 + (24892729062597149834655331100049*e)/(9007199254740992*(1125899906842624*e + 1125899906842624*f - 6448194806345241)) - (3860418273669689*e*(e + f))/(8*(1125899906842624*e + 1125899906842624*f - 6448194806345241))) + abs((4636666003778669*b**2)/(9007199254740992*b + 9007199254740992*c - 6442131581095921) - (4636666003778669*b)/9007199254740992 - (4636666003778669*a)/9007199254740992 + (4474210984776564*b*c)/(9007199254740992*b + 9007199254740992*c - 6442131581095921) + 29870012493936382538794142709149/81129638414606681695789005144064) + abs((8431533077325893*a)/18014398509481984 + (8431533077325893*b)/18014398509481984 - (8431533077325893*b**2)/(16*(1125899906842624*b + 1125899906842624*c - 6448194806345241)) + (708586604185451*b*c)/(4*(1125899906842624*b + 1125899906842624*c - 6448194806345241)) - 54368167798740930523060826625213/20282409603651670423947251286016) + abs((5981047056487669*e)/9007199254740992 + (13453693419063522919576994335923*e)/(9007199254740992*(140737488355328*e + 140737488355328*f - 2249387656040967)) - (5981047056487669*e*(e + f))/(64*(140737488355328*e + 140737488355328*f - 2249387656040967))) + abs((792979490709637*a)/1125899906842624 + (792979490709637*b)/1125899906842624 - (1585958981419274*b**2)/(2251799813685248*b + 2251799813685248*c - 6168967381864879) + (901702497811663*b*c)/(2251799813685248*b + 2251799813685248*c - 6168967381864879) - 4891864612675574504296157138923/2535301200456458802993406410752) + abs((4461181249195911*e)/9007199254740992 + (27520881610876789415202401309769*e)/(9007199254740992*(2251799813685248*e + 2251799813685248*f - 6168967381864879)) - (4461181249195911*e*(e + f))/(4*(2251799813685248*e + 2251799813685248*f - 6168967381864879))) + abs((708586604185451*c)/4503599627370496 + (5277591482040591*d)/9007199254740992 - (708586604185451*c**2)/(4*(1125899906842624*b + 1125899906842624*c - 6448194806345241)) + (8431533077325893*b*c)/(16*(1125899906842624*b + 1125899906842624*c - 6448194806345241)) - 4569104460954436146783095288691/5070602400912917605986812821504) + abs((2035957719017013*b)/144115188075855872 + (2939179565022695*c)/9007199254740992 + (4579658161378192576066497971571*b)/(144115188075855872*(140737488355328*b + 140737488355328*c - 2249387656040967)) + (6611354232449908862093204746065*c)/(9007199254740992*(140737488355328*b + 140737488355328*c - 2249387656040967)) - (2035957719017013*b*(b + c))/(1024*(140737488355328*b + 140737488355328*c - 2249387656040967)) - (2939179565022695*c*(b + c))/(64*(140737488355328*b + 140737488355328*c - 2249387656040967))) + abs((2230056655377591*d)/2251799813685248 + (5981047056487669*e)/9007199254740992 - (5981047056487669*e**2)/(64*(140737488355328*e + 140737488355328*f - 2249387656040967)) - 13453693419063522919576994335923/1267650600228229401496703205376) + abs((854371257949259*d)/9007199254740992 + (4461181249195911*e)/9007199254740992 - (4461181249195911*e**2)/(4*(2251799813685248*e + 2251799813685248*f - 6168967381864879)) - 27520881610876789415202401309769/20282409603651670423947251286016) + abs((854371257949259*d)/9007199254740992 - (901702497811663*c)/2251799813685248 + (901702497811663*c**2)/(2251799813685248*b + 2251799813685248*c - 6168967381864879) - (1585958981419274*b*c)/(2251799813685248*b + 2251799813685248*c - 6168967381864879) + 5562573297146236482969456283777/5070602400912917605986812821504) + abs((3060017963484179*c**2)/(8*(562949953421312*b + 562949953421312*c - 5536725273124715)) - (3608946673948233*d)/4503599627370496 - (3060017963484179*c)/4503599627370496 + (5056216978909333*b*c)/(64*(562949953421312*b + 562949953421312*c - 5536725273124715)) + 16942478794638475145271796383985/2535301200456458802993406410752) + abs((177126692422487*d)/1125899906842624 - (764299361349167*e)/2251799813685248 + (3057197445396668*e**2)/(9007199254740992*e + 9007199254740992*f - 6442131581095921) + 4923717053158911857783000447807/20282409603651670423947251286016) + abs((5277591482040591*d)/9007199254740992 + (3860418273669689*e)/9007199254740992 - (3860418273669689*e**2)/(8*(1125899906842624*e + 1125899906842624*f - 6448194806345241)) - 24892729062597149834655331100049/10141204801825835211973625643008) + abs((5056216978909333*b**2)/(64*(562949953421312*b + 562949953421312*c - 5536725273124715)) - (5056216978909333*b)/36028797018963968 - (5056216978909333*a)/36028797018963968 + (3060017963484179*b*c)/(8*(562949953421312*b + 562949953421312*c - 5536725273124715)) + 27994884333529598097197586465095/20282409603651670423947251286016) + abs((764299361349167*e)/2251799813685248 + (4923717053158911857783000447807*e)/(2251799813685248*(9007199254740992*e + 9007199254740992*f - 6442131581095921)) - (3057197445396668*e*(e + f))/(9007199254740992*e + 9007199254740992*f - 6442131581095921)))]



SOL= Opti(cons,x , 2)
print SOL
```

Comment: Python has a [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) module that you may find useful.

Comment: The fact that you are importing "*" from `sympy` and `z3` means that I will have a hard time finding documentation on functions like `Solver` and `If`.

Comment: It's not clear to me what part of the program doesn't terminate and where the floating-point precision comes into this. Could you elaborate on that? It seems that the program will always run for exactly Max iterations, do you mean that one of the iterations doesn't terminate? Note that Z3 is a precise solver, if you need an imprecise optimization solver other alternatives like Gurobi or CPlex may be much more efficient for your application.